# AttributeError: 'gdstk.Cell' object has no attribute 'get_polygons'

Tags: python

I am new in PIC design and I want to make a simple GDSII design following this script:
https://github.com/BYUCamachoLab/simphony/blob/master/examples/layout_aware.py

which uses gdsfactory and simphony libraries but I consistently encounter this error when I am building a cell:
AttributeError: 'gdstk.Cell' object has no attribute 'get_polygons'

This problem appears when I try to call the grating coupler or the waveguides as a component. On the other hand, the Ybranch (splitters) work just fine.

I have downloaded all the latest versions of gdstk, gdsfactory and simphony but cannot make it work.
Do you know how to overcome this issue? What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. In case anybody finds in the same situation, the problem was with the gdstk library. For whatever reason, the version installed could not be changed and it remained always in 7.0.
By reinstalling Anaconda, the gdstk latest version could be installed without issues, and from there the program worked.